# NSDateFormatter giving me two different days of the week, for the same date

Tags: swift, swift2, nsdate, nsdateformatter

have a bunch of dates, and I am trying to get their days of the week. But whenever, I loop through, even after midnight, the day of the week doesn't change for a few hours, and I don't know why.
Here's my code:

```
func parseArray(array: [HKQuantitySample])
{
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"

for element in array
{
    let startDate: NSDate = element.startDate //example: 2015-11-13 13:30:07 +0000

    let startDateArray = String(startDate).componentsSeparatedByString(" ") // example: ["2015-11-13", "13:46:53", "+0000"]

    let startDateString = startDateArray[0] // example: 2015-11-13
    let startDateTimeString = startDateArray[1] // example: 13:58:39

    let startDateDayOfTheWeek = formatter.stringFromDate(startDate)

    print("startDate: \(startDateString), startTime: \(startDateTimeString), dayOfWeek: \(startDateDayOfTheWeek)")
}
```

Here is what I am getting:

```
startDate: 2015-11-12, startTime: 23:32:01, dayOfWeek: Thursday
startDate: 2015-11-12, startTime: 23:41:19, dayOfWeek: Thursday
startDate: 2015-11-12, startTime: 23:50:36, dayOfWeek: Thursday
```

/* midnight */

```
startDate: 2015-11-13, startTime: 00:07:35, dayOfWeek: Thursday
startDate: 2015-11-13, startTime: 00:19:19, dayOfWeek: Thursday
startDate: 2015-11-13, startTime: 00:32:20, dayOfWeek: Thursday
startDate: 2015-11-13, startTime: 00:41:37, dayOfWeek: Thursday
startDate: 2015-11-13, startTime: 00:55:34, dayOfWeek: Thursday
startDate: 2015-11-13, startTime: 01:04:51, dayOfWeek: Thursday
2016-06-21 17:39:10.446213 appleWatchHealth[1173:238873] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
startDate: 2015-11-13, startTime: 01:14:57, dayOfWeek: Thursday
startDate: 2015-11-13, startTime: 01:24:50, dayOfWeek: Thursday
startDate: 2015-11-13, startTime: 01:36:39, dayOfWeek: Thursday
startDate: 2015-11-13, startTime: 01:45:56, dayOfWeek: Thursday
```

So even after it changes from the 12th to the 13th, it keeps giving me Thursday. However it does change to friday at around 1 pm:

```
startDate: 2015-11-13, startTime: 13:01:31, dayOfWeek: Friday
```

Also, I have no idea what this last line means:

```
2016-06-21 17:39:10.446213 appleWatchHealth[1173:238873] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
```

Comment: Your startDateDayOfTheWeek is based on your local date time since you're using an NSDateFormatter, while the string your building from the raw NSDate is using GMT.

Comment: Ohhh How can I change it so the string is also based on locale time?

Comment: Sure just use another NSDateFormatter to print the date portion of the string in whatever format you like.

Answer (score 0):

String (startDate) uses the description of startDate, which is purely for debugging purposes. You should never, ever use it for something that an enduser sees. Therefore there is no way to make it display anything else than what you see.

NSDateFormatter should be used whenever you want to convert an NSDate to something that the end user sees.